# Re-Enabling Button Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button on a form that gets disabled when the user clicks it.  I then perform some validation on the form and let the user know if there are any errors.  I'm having problems re-enabling the button.  Below is the code that disables the button (rather complicated to stop IE on Windows 8 and up from registering multiple clicks):

```
var alreadySent = false;
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
        $("#submitBtn")
            .click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                if (!alreadySent) {
                    $("#checkInOutForm")
                        .submit();
                    alreadySent = true;
                }
                $(this)
                    .prop("disabled", true);
            });
    });
```

And below is the code that is supposed to re-enable the button or submit the form.  You can also see all the things I have tried to re-enable the button - none of which work - the button remains disabled.

```
function addNewSubmit() {
    if (document.getElementById("actionType").value === "deleteVisit") {
        if (confirm("Deleting a visit cannot be undone.\nAre you sure you wish to continue?")) {
            document.addNew.submit();
        }
    } else {
        var error = checkAddNewRequiredFields();

        if (!error == "") {
            // Re-enable the submit button
            document.getElementById("submitBtn").disabled = false;
            //document.getElementById('submitBtn').removeAttribute("disabled");
            //document.getElementsByTagName("#submitBtn")[0].removeAttribute("disabled");
            //$('#submitBtn').removeAttr('disabled');

            //$('#submitBtn').prop("disabled", false);
            /*$('#submitBtn').each(function() {
                this.disabled = false;
            });*/
            //$("#submitBtn").button('refresh');
            alert(error);
            return false;
        } else {
            document.addNew.submit();
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want to simply refresh the page to re-enable the button - it seems a bit heavy handed just to enable a button!

I am running jQuery Mobile on this page as it is designed to be run from desktops or mobile devices and I have been able to duplicate the fault in the latest versions of IE, Chrome and FF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Gareth

**EDIT**: This button appears on a hidden  that is set to appear as a popup when the user clicks a button.

Comment: Can you post the code that renders the #submitBtn button?

Comment: Does it enters on the `if (!error == "") {` block?

Comment: @Gideon - Yes, it does enter the error block and complete all other items (ie shwing the alert).

Comment: @KristenJukowski - As requested, code that renders the button:  <button id="submitBtn" class="ui-btn-hidden" onclick="return addNewSubmit();" name="submitBtn" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="gear" data-theme="e" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" type="button" data-disabled="true">Add Visit</button>

Comment: Is `this` in the code for `$(this).prop("disabled", true);` the same object as `$('#submitBtn').prop("disabled", false);`? You might be disabling the button, but you could be enabling the wrong element if it's nested.

Comment: @Gareth Please try using `alert($("#submitBtn").length)` to know if the element exists, for all we know the code _may_ indeed works but since the object is _"non-existing"_, therefore you cannot see any changes! Because for me, your code actually works fine as it is.

Comment: @Papa - I believe it should be the same element, as the selection of the submit button occurs higher up the list.  So the $(this) should (?) be referring to the currently selected object.

Comment: @Gideon - I added the .length and it returned 1, so it looks as though we are getting the submit button.  If it's working for you, it must be a combination of other things on the page.  Actually, something that I should have mentioned in the original post (I will amend), is that this button is in a hidden <div> that is set to popup when the user clicks a button.  Could this have something to do with it I wonder...

Comment: @Gareth I believe regardless whether there is that hidden `<div>` or not, your selector should work, since it is not the `<div>` but the `button` that is inside the `$()` operator...

Comment: @Gareth Just making sure, it is `disabled` but still visible, right?

Comment: @Gideon - Grasping at straws at the moment!  I'll hop onto CodePen and try a few things.  The code is working for others, so I suspect something else on the page is causing the issue.

Comment: @Gideon - Indeed it is visible.  After it is disabled, the appearance does not change.  But if you close the popup and then re-show it, the button is greyed out.

Comment: @Gareth Before closing and re-showing that popup, please try this: `alert($("#submitBtn[disabled]").length)` to determine if the button is _already_ disabled, only its not reflecting its state on the screen...

Comment: @Gideon - The alert shows 1 when running the above just before closing the popup.

Comment: @Gareth then therefore it is already working! The real problem is that it is being manifested on the screen (i.e. The button is enabled at the _"back-end"_ but is **still** disabled at the _"front-end"_) which is weird.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, you can use this to enable it

```
 $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled', false);
```

make sure that $('#submitBtn') returns the object and checking of error is okay

Comment: I've already tried that - it's one of the commented out items in the code.  Same result as all the others I'm afraid!

Comment: debug using Chrome developer tool if $('#submitBtn') returns an object.

Comment: @marhs08 - It does return an object in the debug console.  I suspect there is something going on with some other code on the page as it is working for others.  I'll hop on CodePen and have a play.